# Automatically 'select all' in browser address/search bars

Tags: browser

Is it possible to automatically 'select all' when I left click in a browser address/search bar.

I know it's only one more click by right clicking and then choosing 'select all' and I probably sound a bit fussy but it's feature I like.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 64bit, Chrome and Firefox

Thanks in advance.

As an update, Chrome now does this automatically

Comment: then you need to new key to click at address bar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For anyone interested I have found an answer for this, if only in Firefox.

In Firefox url bar type

> about:config

After heeding the "Here be Dragons" warning either search for or scroll to

```
browser.urlbar.doubleClickSelectsAll
```

and

```
browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll
```

Double click to toggle.

Set `browser.urlbar.doubleClickSelectsAll` to `false`
and set `browser.urlbar.clickSelectsAll` to `true`

[image]

This will work in the url bar but not the search bar, I tend to use the url bar for search also so it wont overly bother me.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative option is to double click anywhere in the address bar, which will automatically seleect the entire closest word. In the case of a URL that is the entire line. Concerning the search bar, you can also double click to select a word and triple click to select the entire content.

Comment: fro chrome I think, a click on address will select all. (I am not able to test it now)

Comment: @Zilvador Triple click works well and probably something I could get used too, Thanks

Comment: @Web-E Not in chrome it doesn't

Answer (score 2):

Actually there is a Automatic key for this . I have tried this in Firefox . 
Press <kbd>F6</kbd> Functional key one time . then it will select the address bar automatically .

Comment: I have never grown accustomed to using keyboard shortcuts, I will try between this and the triple click option and see which becomes the more natural to use. Have a feeling it will be the triple click. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisCarter welcome :D

Comment: `Ctrl+L` does th same thing if you do not want to take your hands away from _typing area_